# How is the ability to do something on the fly and the ability to make that same thing permanent referred to in Unix / Linux?

Tags: terminology

I can think of many examples of this...

- You can use the `ip/if*` commands to set your network interface in the here and now, but you can edit a file like `/etc/network/interfaces` to make the changes permanent.
- You can set a bash environment variable by exporting it form the shell, or to make it permanent for your account, you can place the same command in .bashrc
- In `vim` you can `:set nowrap` to make sure the text file you have open doesn't wrap; but you can also add the same command to `.vimrc` to keep this the same everytime you open `vim`.

So given these examples; what is this called?

Comment: i'm not sure if it's called anyhow (i'm curious too though) , it's just referred to as 'make it permanent'

Comment: are you looking for a synonym for this action/activity, which is defined for another operating system ? If so, please indicate what other terms used for similar actions.

Comment: @MelBurslan I have no term, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: I would call it 'changing the configuration', 'changing a config file', 'modifying the default settings', or something along those lines.

Comment: There really ought to be a quick single word term for this.

Comment: If there is a single word term for this, we could have tags that we associate with on the fly and configuration file questions dealing with those particular concepts.

Comment: "transient" and "persistent" are words that immediately spring to mind—certainly I've seen "persistent" in documentation before (though as usual can't find any now).  But they don't describe the concept itself, only actions within it, which I guess is what you're after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [on-the-fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/on-the-fly) and [permanent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/permanent) tags did existed, no such UNIX or Linux specific terms.

Comment: Shouldn't there be tags like that on the Linux site?

Comment: @leeand00 You can create such tags if you have enough reputations (1500 i think) in Unix stack exchange.

Comment: Busted at the moment.  Anybody else?

Comment: @leeand00 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146950/248603